# How can I retrieve all MC in a Stage in AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

How can I retrieve all MC in a Stage?

I want to call addEventListener for all MovieClip present in my stage and if it's possible in a **selected frame number of my scenario**
Something like that pseudo code

```
for(i=0; nbOfChild ; i++)
   if(stage.childAt(i) is MC and isInTheFrameWithLabel('foo') )
     stage.childAt(i).addEventListerner(MyStuff)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty much exactly what you have..

```
for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    var e:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
    if(e is MovieClip)
    {
        // do stuff with e
        trace(e);
    }
}
```

You could also be a tricky trickster and do something like this:

```
/**
 * Iterate through MovieClips within a container and parse them through handler
 * @param container The container to iterate through and find MovieClips in
 * @param handler A function that accepts MovieClip as its only parameter
 */
function each(container:DisplayObjectContainer, handler:Function):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0; i<container.numChildren; i++)
    {
        var e:DisplayObject = container.getChildAt(i);
        if(e is MovieClip) handler(e);
    }
}

// Example
each(this, function(mc:MovieClip):void
{
    trace(mc);
    mc.x += 10;
});
```

Comment: @Ascension Systems What? If you mean I should have done that, you'll only end up with 1 child: [object MainTimeline]

Comment: Nothing just being picky I guess, I see your example would work fine for grabbing all children added to the class that code is within, but I was just pointing out he specifically wanted children added to the stage, so it'd be stage.numChildren and stage.getChildAt(i). Anyway not trying to be one of those nit-picking perfectionist jerks it's just 5 am where I am,  bored/tired etc lol. +1

Comment: No worries man I actually tried that initially but it only yielded 1 child which was the MainTimeline. Odd.

Comment: When you tried that was it code written on the timeline in Flash CS* Pro? Or was it in a DocumentClass? I know if you write code on the timeline the compiler/IDE does some crazyness with merging all that stuff together and yeah you'll get a MainTimeline reference. Oh well.

Comment: Ah good note, I was smashing this out on the timeline. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Ascension Systems good comment I actually put it in the timeline for some test

Answer (score 0):

you should also push those movie clips to an array in order to know the movie clip who has trigger the event, so you would have like:

```
var holdObjects:Array = new Array();
for(var i:int = 0; i<numChildren; i++)
{
    var e:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);
    if(e is MovieClip)
    {
        // do stuff with e
        trace(e);
        e.addEventlistene(...);
        holdObjects.push(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on what you're doing here? Curious. I mean, if you wanted to know the MovieClip that's triggering the event you can use the **target** property on the event that you're parsing to your listener function.

Comment: I don't understand why you use an Array for that?